# Is there a simple way to display both the value and text fields in a drop-down list in MVC (razor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple view dropdownlist in razor,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Client_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and for the controller I have the following viewbag,

```
ViewBag.Client_Id = new SelectList(db.ClientMetadatas, "Client_Id", "Name");
```

Now is it possible to have a simple way, to display the client_id along with the Name in the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating an anonymous class using the `Select` extension method.

```
ViewBag.Client_Id = new SelectList(db.ClientMetadatas.Select(x => new { ClientId = x.Client_Id, CombinedProperty = x.Client_Id.ToString() + " " + x.Name }).ToList(), "ClientId", "CombinedProperty");
```

Please let me know if this was able to assist you!

Comment: Thanks......this works , but I was actually asking if there is an overload of dropdownlist method or any variation method, to directly display both text and value ....

Comment: No there is not.  I'm confused by your question.  A Dropdownlist has a value to be submitted to the server, and text that corresponds to the value.  So if you want to display both the value and the text to the user, then you need to do that in the text parameter.. there wouldn't be a method to accept 2 text values to display to the user.

Comment: Technically, what I showed you is using the only option of the dropdownlist overload to display what you want displayed

Comment: ok if there is no such built-in methods provided then we have to go by the long way.  However I did not mean to submit 2 values, just that the Dropdown would display the id as well along with the names, so users can understand which client_id the name corresponds to while making a selection.

Comment: Yes, what I provided will do exactly that.  It will display both the `id` and the `name` but will only submit the `id`

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered.